# xmlHttp 404 error that works when put into postman

Tags: asp.net, xml, soap

I am using the following method to make a SOAP request to login to a server's API. It works properly when the file is on the server trying to be logged into. When I try to login to the same API on a different server I am getting a 404 error returned.

```
<% @ LANGUAGE = JavaScript %>
<% Response.CharSet="Utf-8" %>
<%
function makeSoapRequest( requestUrl, webServiceName, webMethodName, requestContent )
{
    var xmlHttp = Server.CreateObject( "Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0" );

    var request = '';
    request += "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>";
    request += "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">";
    request += "<soap:Body><" + webMethodName +" xmlns=\"" + webServiceName + "\">";
    request += requestContent;
    request += "</" + webMethodName + "></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>";

    var webServiceMethodName = webServiceName + "/" + webMethodName;
    xmlHttp.open( "post", requestUrl, false );
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader( "Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8" );
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader( "Content-Length", request.length );
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader( "SOAPAction", webServiceMethodName );

    xmlHttp.send( request );

    responseText = xmlHttp.responsetext;

    return responseText;
}
%>
```

To test it out, I printed both requestUrl and request, and used the chrome addon Postman to send the post request and it worked properly.

My question is, is the 404 getting returned because it is sending it to another server? I don't think this would be the case, but not 100% sure. If not, why would I be getting a 404 from the code execution, but not the postman request?

Answer (score 0):

try change `xmlHttp.open( "post", requestUrl, false );` to `xmlHttp.open( "POST", requestUrl, false );`